# Torchtext on Colab: Cannot import name 'dtype_to_attr'

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory, tokenize, torchtext

having trouble importing torchtext.data or .datasets with the following error on Google Colab. Tried to 1/ upgrade torch to 1.7, 2/ upgrade torchtext to 0.4 or 0.5 or latest as per some posts. But none seem to help.
Wondering if you have any insights here? Trying to import to embed / tokenize word sequences.

---

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
1 # For data loading.
----> 2 from torchtext import data, datasets

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchtext/data/field.py in ()
8 from .dataset import Dataset
9 from .pipeline import Pipeline
---> 10 from .utils import get_tokenizer, dtype_to_attr, is_tokenizer_serializable
11 from ..vocab import Vocab, SubwordVocab
12

ImportError: cannot import name 'dtype_to_attr'